# Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on a non-object

Tags: magento

When I try to placing an order, while selecting the shipping method an error is getting saying

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on a non-object in /home/exclus31/public_html/../../../app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php on line 40
```

But there is no problem for placing the order and got the confirmation message for the particular order.

Any one know why this error is shown and a solution for this?

Comment: what version of Magento?

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with your use of ../../../

Answer (score 4):

I had this error as well. It was because I was calling `getLayout()` in my `IndexAction()` before I had loaded the layout. Just call `loadLayout()` first, like so:

```
public function IndexAction() {
  $this->loadLayout(); // do this first
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Title')); // then this works
  $this->renderLayout(); // render as usual
}
```

I hope this helps